# rails render json with query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

I would like to include a username (a column in the user table) for each review in the following json response

```
render json: Doctor.all, :include => :reviews
```

What's the best way to accomplish this? Should I include the username in the reviews table or make a query before returning the json?

The reviews table schema is includes `content`, `user_id` and `doctor_id`

If it helps, I've included the relations below

```
class Doctor < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :reviews
  has_many :users, through: :reviews
end

class Review <ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :doctor
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :reviews
  has_many :doctors, through: :reviews
end
```

Comment: Try this: `render json: Doctor.all.to_json(:include => {:reviews => {:include => :user => { :only => :username }}})`

Comment: @ali thanks :). Here is the syntax I used `:include => {:reviews => {:include => {:user => { :only => :username }}}}`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @ali in the comments.

I used `:include => {:reviews => {:include => {:user => { :only => :username }}}}`